# Why won't all getssl output log from cron

Tags: cron, ssl, logging

I have a LAMP server set up to serve a handful of sites, and I am using the getssl script to create the LetsEncrypt certs for those sites.

I had set up a cron job to renew those certs as recommended, but so far, it has not actually managed to renew them for me, and I find that they are expired every 3 mo, and I have to run it manually. I have "fixed" my cron line several times, and thought I had it, as nothing seems broke, until, well, its broke. I think I'm just not getting the errors properly logged, so that I can see what the problem is.

Sure enough, when I run manually, I get a bunch of stuff reported that is not showing up in my logs. Here's a manual run:

```
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:~$ sudo /opt/getssl -u -a && sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
Check all certificates
mydomain.com: certificate is valid for more than 30 days (until Jul 15 18:43:20 2020 GMT)
myotherdomain.com: certificate is valid for more than 30 days (until Jul 15 18:43:36 2020 GMT)
mythirddomain.net: certificate is valid for more than 30 days (until Jul 15 18:43:46 2020 GMT)
[ ok ] Reloading apache2 configuration (via systemctl): apache2.service.
```

But in my log file, all I get from cron is:

```
Check all certificates
Reloading apache2 configuration (via systemctl): apache2.service.
```

I'm guessing if those "...certificate is valid for..." messages aren't logging, any message that might tell my why real work isn't being done (when they aren't valid) probably isn't either.

I've tried three variants of my cron line, trying to get a log, all with the same result. My guess is any of these should work (the last, of course, would land in syslog - I'd be fine with that if that's what I can get):

```
* * * * * /opt/getssl -u -a >> /var/log/getssl.log 2>&1 && /etc/init.d/apache2 reload >> /var/log/getssl.log 2>&1

* * * * * /opt/getssl -u -a 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/getssl.log && /etc/init.d/apache2 reload 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/getssl.log

* * * * * /opt/getssl -u -a 2>&1 | /usr/bin/logger -t getssl && /etc/init.d/apache2 reload 2>&1 | /uar/bin/logger -t getssl
```

(obviously my timing is set so I can debug it for the moment)

Also, when I run the tee version of the command, logging and all, manually, I am getting those extra lines in the log. It seems to be just when cron runs it that they are omitted.

My real question is about the logging, but of course, style points if you see why the getssl is failing as well.

Is there an error in my crontab?

Comment: `cron` does not offer full bash-like command lines. It's simpler to put your commands inside `bash` scripts, where you can debug easily, and have your `crontab` entry simply invoke the `bash` script.

Comment: as already mentioned by @waltinator the cron is not a full bash-like shell, another way to debug quick and dirty is to load the environment as like bash and see there if it works (for example maybe tee is not in the path of cron shell)

Comment: Thanks @waltinator and @AtomiX84. I hadn't thought to check what shell cron uses. So based on your feedback, I've tried a number of things. First, as @waltinator suggested, I put my commands in a script and invoked the script with `bash /path/myscript.sh`  in the crontab. I also tried altering the existing cron command with `bash -c "/opt/getssl..."`, and I also tried setting `SHELL` and `BASH_ENV` in the crontab to use the same bash environment as my session. All of these are still producing the same results originally reported.